# CRM for online betting platform

Tags: halal-haram, work

The main focus for the position currently being offered is development and maintenance of our Customer Relationship Management (CRM) product. The CRM product forms the backbone for our online gaming customers. The CRM links together player account information, transactions (deposits/withdrawals), customer support, and APIs with 3rd party game providers.

I am a software developer and I have been offered the following position in an online betting platform

```
The high-level task list of the CRM team is to:

develop new modules for our CRM product
maintain and debug modules in the CRM product
integrate with 3rd party APIs
complete other C++ coding projects outside the CRM base as needed.
The majority of EAS products are database-driven. Working knowledge of SQL querying and basic DB schema is a must: all applicants must know how to connect to, query, and fetch/process results from a database as well as update records in order to be eligible for this position.
```

I thought since I'm not directly involved with the betting platform itself this might be okay, but since I'm not sure, I wanted to ask if it is halal or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for personal advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my personnal advice is don't work for this, why ?
I remember long time ago (3+ years ago) when i was interested in ads based earning such with bux sites etc...i have read something said by a mufti or a religious person who had knowledge in the Deen.
Let's say it a fatwa, it said that you cannot earn money with something related to something haram, let's say you earn money doing ads, if any of your ads contain something haram (bedding, alcohol etc....) your money is haram.
So don't work for a company that you know that the earning's they get is surely haram.
Staying religious and follow the ethics is really far better and has many good returns than earning money no matter how much in something haram.
May Allah Subhannahu'Wa'Taala guide you to the right choice.